# How could I crawl this website with python requests

Tags: python, web-crawler

I tried to use `python requests` to keep the session during crwal data,

However, the problem is that I couldn't find what method do the website use for their query method.

What the query method does this website use ?

https://www.flyvair.com/en/

[image]

What want to crawl with this code section but it doesn't work.

```
URL = 'http://www.flyvair.com/en/'
POST_URL= 'http://book.flyvair.com/en/Search'
login_data = dict(select_return="Oneway", OriginStation="TPE", DestinationStation="DMK", DepartureDate='29/10/2015', Adults=1, Children=0)
resp = client.post(POST_URL, data=login_data)#, headers=dict(Referer=URL), allow_redirects=True)
```

Comment: It uses GET method. Actually, all data are coming from the json file using GET method [book.json](https://www.flyvair.com/src/js/locales/en/book.json)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, but things are not so trivial, `book.json` only return  i18N translate words, not including the most critical flights information. i use the chrome developer tool to inspect the network request :)